# How to set Android: layout_width and Android: layout_height programmatically for GridView

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, gridview

I am using Android gridview in Xamarin C# project. Here I want to set Android: layout_width and Android: layout_height dynamically from cs page (from code) for layout mode/portrait mode.

Here I have used `layout_width` and `layout_height` in XAML page, but I want to do it from code.

How to do this?

```
   <GridView
   android:layout_width="400dp"
   android:layout_height="200dp"            
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:columnWidth="95dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"                
   android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
   android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
   android:id="@+id/GridMiddle" />
```

Here is the code behind module:

```
int LayoutOrientation = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Orientation;
if (LayoutOrientation != 0)
{
    try
    {
        // landscape view                                
        var Lin = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LinLay);
        Lin.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        GridView GVMiddle = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.GridMiddle);
        GVMiddle.NumColumns = 6;                       
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.Message.ToString();
    }            
}
```

Comment: Did you try setLayoutParams function ?

Comment: No @AlperenKantarcı , can you please tell me how to achieve that.

Comment: I don't know C# but in java GVMiddle.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(400, 200)); will make your width 400 and height 200. You should look at xamarin documentation for layout params.